# Mongodb: multiple objects in an array

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and I have been assigned a task to extract data from mongoDB and create a csv and load it to Oracle database. Below is the data in Mongodb

```
{{
"_id":"69ajdslsdfdksjfef9",
"col1":"456780",
"refNum":"ref001"
}
{
  "clients":{
              "CLI_1": "9876547390",
              "CLI_2": "fsdfasl"
}
{"names":[
{
  "first":"dfsakfj",
  "middle":"hgfgas",
  "last":"komdssdfsd"
},
{
  "first":"dfskdajf",
  "middle": "fgjfgjfl",
  "last": "ghfghsdklfg"
}]}

second row from collection

{{
"_id":"69ajdslsdfdksjfef9",
"col1":"456780",
"refNum":"ref001"
}
{
  "clients":{
              "CLI_1": "9876547390",
              "CLI_2": "fsdfasl"
}
{"names":[
{
  "first":"dfsakfj",
  "middle":"hgfgas",
  "last":"komdssdfsd"
}]}
```

I am using pymongo utility to query and create a dataframe before generating the csv file. However, I am able to create a dataframe but not able parse "names" properly as it is inconsistent when compared between the rows. Could anyone please share how to parse and create a csv with fields _id, first, middle, last

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mongodb aggregation pipeline named $unwind which can help you with the task to flatten the names array so it is suitable for csv output as follow:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $unwind: "$names"
 },
 {
   $project: {
    _id: 1,
    first: "$names.first",
    middle: "$names.middle",
    last: "$names.last"
   }
 }
])// _id, first, middle, last
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IwiV-dA-Xj_)